# Vuejs Transition

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to add transition when the values get changes but cannot accomplish it. I need to change the background when the values get updated.

Can anyone help me out?

Codesandbox Link - [Vuejs Transition](https://codesandbox.io/s/transition-hbdw7?file=/src/App.vue:)

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="box">
      <div v-if="change > 0">
        <transition name="increase">
          <span>+ {{ amount }} </span></transition
        >
      </div>
      <div v-else-if="change < 0">
        <transition name="decrease">
          <span>- {{ amount }}</span>
        </transition>
      </div>
      <div v-else>{{ amount }}</div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <button @click="generate">Update</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      change: 2,
      amount: 100,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    generate() {
      var amounts = [100, 110, 85, 75, 190];
      let changes = [-1.2, -5, 2, 5, 1, 7];
      this.amount = amounts[Math.floor(Math.random() * amounts.length)];
      this.change = changes[Math.floor(Math.random() * changes.length)];
    },
  },
  created() {},
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.box {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 1em 2em;
}
@keyframes higher {
  50% {
    background: rgba(50, 199, 135, 0.2);
    color: #32c787;
  }
}
@keyframes lower {
  50% {
    background: rgba(255, 86, 82, 0.2);
    color: #ff5652;
  }
}
.increase-enter {
  animation: higher 0.5s;
}
.decrease-enter {
  animation: lower 0.5s;
}
</style>
```

P.S - Ignore this, posted because my text is too short. IT is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `key` to inform transition there is a difference of the element so it can trigger the animation again.

Also, use the `-active` class to apply animation during entering phase.

https://codesandbox.io/s/transition-forked-vg5pu?file=/src/App.vue

```js
<transition name="increase">
    <span :key="amount + change">+ {{ amount }}</span>
</transition>

...

.increase-enter-active {
  animation: higher 0.5s;
}
```